# Adjust DB2 keepalive settings for a Python Cloud Foundry app on IBM Cloud

Tags: python, db2, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, tcp-keepalive

I have a working Python Cloud Foundry app on Bluemix / IBM Cloud that connects to, and otherwise works well with a DB2 on Cloud instance on Bluemix / IBM Cloud.

However, after long intervals (I haven't been able to measure the time), the connection to DB2 closes, and my queries fail. I could modify my code to check for this, but it would be great to be able to adjust the TCP keepalive settings. Something along the lines of [this](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/301273/db2-keepalive-timeout-settings/).

Would greatly appreciate any pointers. I'm not sure how one adjusts the client-side settings on a Python Cloud Foundry app.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you using explicit-transactions or autocommit?  If you are using autocommit (i.e. not using transactions) , are you using pconnect persistent-connections?

Comment: It seems like you're seeing a pooled connection that is getting timed out fail on re-use. Hmm.. Keepalive won't help those cases. Question is what is causing the connection to be closed? Db2 on Cloud does not have any idle connection thresholds. Perhaps a firewall some were in between? Also, are you using the free tier for Db2 on Cloud? That will help diagnose since there's different limitations on the free plan.

Comment: @mao I changed my code yesterday to start using `ibm_db.pconnect()` instead of `ibm_db.connect()`. Hopefully that'll help. I use explicit transactions. I'll keep you posted as I monitor the app.

Comment: @SilentSteel Yes, I'm indeed using the free tier for DB2 on Cloud. I also bound the DB2 instance to my Cloud Foundry app once I noticed this timeout behavior. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I believe the pconnect is not suitable if you use explicit transactions, check documentation.

Comment: @mao Got it, thanks. I'll check out the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing this using a Python Flask Cloud Foundry app and a Db2 on Cloud Lite plan instance.  My connections seem to stay alive for hours. It might be the python application you are running that has some kind of timeout.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this has been a puzzling issue.

Comment: Some observations:

 - smaller queries work fine
 - long-running query from app running locally works fine
 - same long-running query from app running on Bluemix fails
 - same long-running query against a different db2 instance (enterprise) works fine


I agree there could be other issues at play here. For example, I have multiple CRUD operations happening across processes, and that may have some effect. Its puzzling that it works fine locally but not on Bluemix.

In any case, I've switched to a DB2 Enterprise plan, and so far, the issue isn't showing up.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a satisfactory resolution. Like @jackic23 mentioned, there may be other factors at play. Few things:

- The problem is hard to replicate
- The app works fine on localhost, but not when deployed
- I do have other simultaneous CRUD operations happening, which may be potentially conflicting somehow. There could be a race condition that somehow never happens on localhost.
- My flask app is deployed using `gunicorn`, which was killing the worker thread after 30 seconds, so the DB connection terminated mid-query. I adjusted the timeout to 75 seconds, but then the query started returning in under 1 s.

At this point, I have switched to an Enterprise DB2 plan, and the app is working fine. To @jackic23's point, there may still be something else going on here (in my app's code) that may eventually need to be figured out.

For now, I'm moving on. Thank you @jackic23 for looking into this!

Comment: Puzzling indeed, glad you were able to workaround it. Maybe someone else using `gunicorn` can come along and solve that worker thread mystery. Best of luck to you Deven